# Close CSS full screen menu onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, onclick

I cannot implement a solution (CSS or JS) so I can **close** the following navigation menu after clicking on the `<a>` link. I have tried to be minimalistic without using div and nav, but it's very hard to accomplish the final goal.

[My Codepen example](https://codepen.io/NickDimou/pen/VwKemQa)

I have studied multiple examples including [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516898/css-inline-js-menu-onclick), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560986/full-screen-overlay-menu-pure-css-close-it-by-clicking-the-menu-link), [3](https://codepen.io/vladaoleynik/pen/vExKxJ) with no success. Can you point me to the right direction or give me a hand please?

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: "Verdana", serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
label .menu {
  position: fixed;
  right:-45px;
  top: -45px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #F7CC26;
  border-radius:50%;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #072C7D, 0 0 0 0 #072C7D;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label .ha {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 24px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2.5px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
label .ha:after, label .ha:before {
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #9CBEE3;
}
label .ha:before {
  top: -10px;
}
label .ha:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
label input {
  display: none;
}
label input:checked + .menu {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw #F7CC26, 0 0 0 100vh #F7CC26;
  border-radius: 0;
}
label input:checked + .menu .ha {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
label input:checked + .menu .ha:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  bottom: 0;
}
label input:checked + .menu .ha:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 0;
}
label input:checked + .menu + ul {
  opacity: 1;
}
label input:checked + .menu2 + ul{opacity:0}

label ul {
  z-index: 200;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: fixed;
  text-align:center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.25s 0s ease-in-out;
}
label a {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  color: #9CBEE3;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
<input type="checkbox"></input>
<span class="menu">
<span class="ha"></span>
</span>
<ul>
<li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
<li><a href="#educ">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#free">Free Samples</a></li>
<li><a href="#video">Video Review</a></li>
<li><a href="#books">Other Books</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</label>

<div id="free">Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively. Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively. Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively.</div>
<br>
<div id="video">Wikis, chat messages, or formal documentation for knowledge management aren’t effective. Our question and answer format is a proven approach for accessing the right information in less time.</div><br>
<div id="intro">Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively. Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively. Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively.</div>
<br>
<div id="educ">Wikis, chat messages, or formal documentation for knowledge management aren’t effective. Our question and answer format is a proven approach for accessing the right information in less time.</div><br>
<div id="books">Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively. Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively. Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively.</div>
<br>
<div id="contact">Wikis, chat messages, or formal documentation for knowledge management aren’t effective. Our question and answer format is a proven approach for accessing the right information in less time.</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need javascript here, for this I have made few changes to your code

1. In HTML, I have added common class as `.nav-link` for all the navigation links.
2. And added following javascript code:

```js
function addListenersToLinks() {
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a.nav-link');
  
  Array.from(navLinks).forEach(navLink => {
    navLink.addEventListener('click', event => {
      document.querySelector('#menu-checkbox').checked = false;
    })
  })  
}

document.body.onload = addListenersToLinks();
```

I have created one function here, as `addListenersToLinks()` which is called on load of the body element. Following is the explanation to the function definition.

- This function grabs all the links having class as `a.nav-link` using the `document.querySelectorAll()` function.
- `Array.from(navLinks)` converts `navLinks` element collection into array and  it is then looped through each element using the `forEach`.
- Then for each element added a click event listener which will make sure that the checkbox is in unchecked state (if checked, it is switched to unchecked) and the animation will kick in.

Here's the working example:

```js
function addListenersToLinks() {
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a.nav-link');
  
  Array.from(navLinks).forEach(navLink => {
    navLink.addEventListener('click', event => {
      document.querySelector('#menu-checkbox').checked = false;
    })
  })  
}

document.body.onload = addListenersToLinks();
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: "Verdana", serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
label .menu {
  position: fixed;
  right:-45px;
  top: -45px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #F7CC26;
  border-radius:50%;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #072C7D, 0 0 0 0 #072C7D;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label .ha {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 24px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2.5px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
label .ha:after, label .ha:before {
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #9CBEE3;
}
label .ha:before {
  top: -10px;
}
label .ha:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
label input {
  display: none;
}
label input:checked + .menu {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw #F7CC26, 0 0 0 100vh #F7CC26;
  border-radius: 0;
}
label input:checked + .menu .ha {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
label input:checked + .menu .ha:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  bottom: 0;
}
label input:checked + .menu .ha:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 0;
}
label input:checked + .menu + ul {
  opacity: 1;
}
label input:checked + .menu2 + ul{opacity:0}

label ul {
  z-index: 200;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: fixed;
  text-align:center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.25s 0s ease-in-out;
}
label a {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  color: #9CBEE3;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
<input id="menu-checkbox" type="checkbox"></input>
<span class="menu">
<span class="ha"></span>
</span>
<ul>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="#educ">About</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="#free">Free Samples</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="#video">Video Review</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="#books">Other Books</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</label>

<div id="free">Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively. Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively. Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively.</div>
<br>
<div id="video">Wikis, chat messages, or formal documentation for knowledge management aren’t effective. Our question and answer format is a proven approach for accessing the right information in less time.</div><br>
<div id="intro">Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively. Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively. Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively.</div>
<br>
<div id="educ">Wikis, chat messages, or formal documentation for knowledge management aren’t effective. Our question and answer format is a proven approach for accessing the right information in less time.</div><br>
<div id="books">Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively. Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively. Our mission is to help developers write the script of the future. This means helping you find and hire skilled developers for your business and providing them the tools they need to share knowledge and work effectively.</div>
<br>
<div id="contact">Wikis, chat messages, or formal documentation for knowledge management aren’t effective. Our question and answer format is a proven approach for accessing the right information in less time.</div>
```

Comment: I was studying for a solution for 5 hours trying so many different perspectives. But you gave a very elegant solution that works. You cannot escape from JS after all. Thank you so much!